# How do I element-wise multiply an array of 6 elements with an array of 12 elements with the smaller array repeating?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have an array [x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6] and another array [y1, y2, y3,...y12].

I want to element-wise multiply the two arrays so that I get an array like:
[x1*y1, x2*y2....x1*y7, x2*y8...x6*y12]

I thought numpy broadcasting would take care of it but it needs them to be the same shape.

Comment: `np.tile(arr1,2) * np.array(array2)`?

Comment: along the same lines, what if I had (x,y) and (d1, d2, d3) and I wanted it in the order as (x*d1, x*d2, x*d3, y*d1, y*d2, y*d3)

Comment: Now that is a case of broadcasting: `(arr1[:,None] * arr2).ravel()`.

Answer (score 2):

#### `np.resize`

```
x = np.array([1, 2, 3])
y = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])

np.resize(x, y.size) * y

array([ 1,  4,  9,  4, 10, 18])
```

---

`np.resize` will even work if the length of `y` is not a multiple of the length of `x`.  It will keep filling in values from `x`, cycling through them until a length matching that of `y` is achieved.

```
x = np.array([1, 2, 3])
y = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])

np.resize(x, y.size) * y

array([ 1,  4,  9,  4, 10, 18,  7, 16])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `itertools.cycle`, `zip`, and listcomp

```
from itertools import cycle

x = np.arange(1,6)
y = np.arange(1,12)

list(zip(cycle(x), y))

Out[1758]:
[(1, 1),
 (2, 2),
 (3, 3),
 (4, 4),
 (5, 5),
 (1, 6),
 (2, 7),
 (3, 8),
 (4, 9),
 (5, 10),
 (1, 11)]


[i*j for i, j in zip(cycle(x), y)]

Out[1759]: [1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 6, 14, 24, 36, 50, 11]
```